# Can I group or hide functions in pgAdmin4?

Tags: pgadmin

I am using PostGIS, so my database has about 1K functions.

[image]

Looking for "my" functions in that mess is annoying.
Can I somehow group or hide some functions? I was thinking of a functionality I'd seen in an SQL Server [plugin](https://www.sqltreeo.com/img/Rebranding/project-teamwork.png). Maybe something similar for pgAdmin4 exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not an 100% answer to the exact question, it seems that at least PostGIS functions can be "grouped" in a schema of my choice if it's at least PostGIS 2.3:

https://postgis.net/2017/11/07/tip-move-postgis-schema/

The main points of the above link:

```
CREATE SCHEMA postgis;
 
ALTER DATABASE mydb 
SET search_path = public,postgis;

UPDATE pg_extension 
  SET extrelocatable = TRUE 
    WHERE extname = 'postgis';
 
ALTER EXTENSION postgis 
  SET SCHEMA postgis;
 
ALTER EXTENSION postgis 
  UPDATE TO "2.4.1next";
 
ALTER EXTENSION postgis 
  UPDATE TO "2.4.1";
```

This will move all PostGIS functions to a scheme named "PostGIS", that pgadmin can expand/collapse.